# Why do all steady state probabilities have the same denominator?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have noted that the steady state probabilities of an irreducible Markov chain can be written as **fractions** that have the **same denominator**. Is there any result about this property? What does this denominator represent?

**Example**

Let us consider a Markov chain with the following transition probabilities:

$P = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
p & 1-p & 0   \\
q & 0   & 1-q \\
1 - r & 0 & r \\
\end{array}\right]$

The steady state distribution is:

$\left(\dfrac{1 - r}{pq + pr - 2p - q - 2r + 3}, \dfrac{1 - p - r(1 - p)}{pq + pr - 2p - q - 2r + 3}, \dfrac{1 - p - q(1 - p)}{pq + pr - 2p - q - 2r + 3}\right)$

As we can see, all these fractions have $pq + pr - 2p - q - 2r + 3$ in the denominator. I've found that this observation is "always" preserved.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What you say doesn't make sense, no matter what number $a$ is, you can always write them as $a=\frac{x}{\text{your expression}}$, for a well chosen $x$. You may ask why the number x can be expressed nicely in this case, but it's "just" because calculating the steady state distribution is solving a linear system, so the expressions will be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steady state is the solution of a system of linear equations. As such, it can be obtained by dividing suitable determinants, which themselves are polynomial expressions in the given entries. As it is always the same deteminant that occurs in the denominator, your observation follows.

Comment: Thanks Tryss and Hagen for your help! Your answer seems logical.